# Eclipse doesn't format makefiles correctly

Tags: eclipse, makefile

Eclipse generates this makefile automatically from precompiler configuration, but it either doesn't insert TAB or inserts new line unintensionaly.

it causes error:

```
Src/subdir.mk:47: *** missing separator.  Stop.
```

line looks like this:

```
    arm-none-eabi-gcc ${cross_toolchain_flags} -D__weak=__attribute__((weak)) -D
__packed=__attribute__((__packed__)) -D
USE_HAL_DRIVER -D
```

A lot of people had same issue, most of them resolved it by updating eclipse. I've tried several versions and still nothing.

Has anyone had this problem? and if so is there a way to fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you have configured Eclipse to wrap overlong lines.
Try to disable this feature.